# Exe to Open a file

Tags: vb.net, desktop

I have a folder with six Excel files. They are clones of each other with friendly names appended at the end. The Excel workbook connects to a single database in the same folder. The Excel files are used via desktop shortcuts on different PCs on the LAN. As the apps can be used by multiple people at the same time, it is necessary to have separate Excel files for the front end.

I would like to create an Exe (instead of the simple shortcut, that will open a selected file from the six and then remember which was selected from that desktop.

This is one of my first attempts at vb.net

```
    Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        Dim Bfld As String, sFileName as string
        Bfld = Application.StartupPath 
        ' Say, Bfld is "D:\TestFolder"

       '  Populate a list box here with files with names containing ""MyExcelFileClient*.xlsm"
       '  sFileName = selected listbox item
         sFileName ="MyExcelFileClient1.xlsm"   ' Hard coded with ...Client1.xlsm for testing


        Bfld = Bfld & "\" &  sFileName 
        Label1.Text = Bfld
    '  Wait timer 6 seconds with countdown label in Form1
        ShellExecute(Bfld)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Function ShellExecute(ByVal File As String) As Boolean
        Dim myProcess As New Process
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = File
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
        myProcess.Start()
        myProcess.Dispose()
    End Function
End Class
```

I would be grateful for help with populating the list box in Form1 with the 6 matching files.
Selecting any of the files, will remember the choice (Bfld) until it is changed by the user.
If label1 is empty, the form1 should remain on the screen.
If label1 has data (populated with Bfld), a countdown of 6 seconds should close Form1 and run the shellExecute function.
6 seconds should be enough time for the user to change the file previously selected.
Closing Form1 or clicking on a button should run the ShellExecute function immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I would approach this. Set up a form with one label to show the file name and two buttons. One button to change the selected file and one button to actually start Excel. A timer is a bad idea. You can't tell when a user will be interrupted.

You will need to set up a Setting to Project Properties. Be sure to scope to User so the value can be changed.
[image]

When the program starts, the `Form.Load` will run. The code checks the user settings for `ExcelPath`. The label is filled with only the file name for simplicity but the Form level variable `FilePathToOpen` stores the complete path. If no path is found we call the `ChangePath` method. The same method is called from `btnChangePath` is the user wants to change the file.

The `ChangePath` method makes use of the `OpenFileDialog`. The setting is changed and automatically saved on closed, the Form level variable is reset and the label displays the new selection.

The button the actually runs Excel starts by checking if there is a value for `FilePathToOpen`. `Using...End Using` blocks handle the Dispose method even if there is an error.

```
Private FilePathToOpen As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = Path.GetFileName(My.Settings.ExcelPath)
    FilePathToOpen = My.Settings.ExcelPath
    If Label1.Text = "" Then
        ChangePath()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnChangePath_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChangePath.Click
    ChangePath()
End Sub

Private Sub ChangePath()
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog()
    OFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\maryo\OneDrive\Documents\Excel"
    OFD.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlxs)|*.xlsx"
    OFD.Title = "Select File to Open"
    If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        My.Settings.ExcelPath = OFD.FileName
        FilePathToOpen = OFD.FileName
        Label1.Text = Path.GetFileName(OFD.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnOpenExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenExcel.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePathToOpen) Then
        Using myProcess As New Process
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = FilePathToOpen
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
            myProcess.Start()
        End Using
        Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You must choose a file.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dijkgraaf  Thank you for your reply. As there are 6 files, I prefer to pre-populate a listbox. Then, just as in the case of a shortcut, I would like the choice (path and filename) persisted until the 'target file' is changed again by the user.  Example of path = "M:\ABC\".  Example of selected file = "MyExcelFileClient4.xlsm".  M:\ABC would be where the VB.net .exe is also saved.  Therefore M:\ABC should be fetched, so too the 6 files.  But, as this is to be a clone of a normal shortcut, the selected file persists until changed. I agree that the changepath sub would be more flexible.

Comment: Also.  The Excel apps may be used by more than one person from different PCs. A desktop shortcut to this compiled .exe (which is in lieu of a normal shortcut), should remember the selection from the individual PC.  Each PC will have its own selected .xlsm file. Would writing to registry be a better solution? If so, please advise how to in VB.net.